# Set all selected objects to be displayed as wireframe

Tags: workflow, 3d-view

I have positioned blocks as a rough draft of the area I plan to build.

I did this with the high-poly models and high-res textures but I have to replace them all with the low-poly, low-res version of the basic building block.

So now, I have to duplicate the low-poly many times and move them all into place and I would like to use the high-poly scene as a guide for rotating and placing the new assets.

However, it will be very difficult to do this if they are all shaded and the same problem will happen if they are all in wireframe.

I'd like to be able to select all the objects from the high-poly scene and change the view for them to be wireframe without having to do each object separately.

If we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, a menu will pop-up that allows us to transfer attributes to several models all at once so my question is this:

Can we do something similar with the Draw Mode setting in the Object Properties?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

1. Select them all and set the *Max draw type* to wire.
2. Right click on the max draw type menu and select *Copy to selected.*

   [image]

This works for many buttons and settings across blender.