# How to access Object Display properties?

Tags: interface

I'm trying to change properties so that I map have edges drawn over the object when in object mode.
The standard google answer is to use Object->Properties->Display then click on wire etc.
There is even graphic of the display panel in the manual.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/_images/editors_3dview_object_properties_display.png
(from page: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/display.html)

Problem is, the display panel I see is quite different.

[image: display pane on properties (N) panel]

Since the manual is for 2.78 I figure there must be a different panel that I haven't found yet.

So, looking for a clue on how to access this display panel.
If that's not available. Is there another way to have wire frame overlay the texture view when in object mode?

Comment: I suggest adding a picture of the display panel you are seeing.

Comment: This is Display rollout in the Properties shelf in the 3D Viewport, you're searching for the Display rollout in the [Properties editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/properties_editor.html) > Object tab. See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12213/set-all-selected-objects-to-be-displayed-as-wireframe, for multiple objects - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15888/how-to-make-objects-draw-transparent-wireframe-in-the-viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this from the Object properties as shown below:

[image]