# Is there a global wire (display) option, not wireframe mode?

Tags: mesh

I apologize if this is a duplicate question. I have searched the exchange, google and in Blender itself. I cannot find an answer to my question.

I am in Blender 2.79.

Is there a way to turn on a global 'wire' mode (not wireframe mode, not shortcut Z) for all shaded objects, not just the selected?

The only option I know of at the moment is to select an object, go to the object properties panel, and turn on the 'wire' option under display.

[image]

But that only works on the selected object/solid/mesh, whatever you want to call it.

I'm looking for a way to do this as a one button toggle, without having to select anything. It's either on for all objects or it's off for all objects.

For those familiar with Maya, it's the same as the 'wireframe on shaded' option.

Thank you in advance,

Jim

Comment: 'Wireframe'  is one of the display options in the header.. or shortcut Z..  is this not what you want?

Comment: As one way you can do the same as here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12213/set-all-selected-objects-to-be-displayed-as-wireframe but for Wire option (also maybe for Display All Edges as well)

Comment: edited original question. Hope that clarifies what I am looking for.

Comment: What I generally meant with comment above is "no there isn't default way to do it" (maybe some addons though I'm not aware of them. There's also Freestyle though it's complete render engine which might be overkill). Solution to select object/s and enable Wire (for multiple hold Alt while clicking) is a workaround to work with this. It's possible also to create shortcut for this option to run it from keyboard and save some time for searching in settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently 2.80 version only has global "wireframe displaying" option in overlays:

[image]

If you need a solution for 2.79, you can find some addons, witch toggle this settings for all objects in scene. For example:

https://meshlogic.github.io/posts/blender/addons/toggle-object-wire/

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why **Wireframe Mode** is not what you require, but here are few ways of getting **Wireframe** for different circumstances.

Set the **Maximum Draw Type**. Must be done per object(*)
[image: Maximum draw type]

Create a **Wireframe Material**
[image: Wireframe node setup]

If you want to affect multiple objects with multiple materials
[image: collection of objects with different materials]

Set the **Scene Material**. Clear it again to return to the original materials. Has the drawback of only affecting the final render and not the render view.

[image: Scene material setting]

here is an alternate wireframe material without **Transparency**
[image: alternate wireframe node setup]

(*) If the **Maximum Draw Type** is what you need, but have a large number of objects then use Python to script the process.

If none of these work for you and the result you want is in the rendered output, do some research on **Freestyle**.

Comment: Because having to select everything, one by one, is a PITA.